# Python time() object

Tags: python

I'm having some trouble with the time() object (from threading). I'm setting it when i send a UDP packet and close it if i receive a reply. I then set it again when i send a new packet. I do this to get a timeout if I don't receive any thing.
The problem is that when a timeout event occurs a new one occurs almost immediately after the first one. I cant figure out what I am doing wrong. Any ideas?

I'm setting it like this:

```
self.server.timer = Timer(10, self.server.timeout, ())
```

and stopping like:

```
self.server.timer.cancel()
```

Trying to make a simple example:

```
import threading
from threading import Timer

class RequestHandler1(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):
  def handle(self):  
    try:
       self.server.timer.cancel()
    except:
       pass
    # do someting with the recived data
    if imNotDone:
      self.sendNewPacket()

  def sendNewPacket(self):
      self.server.timer = Timer(10, self.server.timeout, ())    
      peer.sendData("somedata")

  def timeout(self):
       self.server.timer = Timer(10, self.server.timeout, ())    
       peer.sendData("somedata")
```

Comment: Examples would be useful if you want anyone to help solve your problem. Just [keep them simple](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: Perhaps your logic is creating more than one Timer, once started they are not garbage-collected by going out of scope. I would pass a different string parameter in every point that Timer() is created, so you can print it at timeout(self, somestring) and check where the timer came from.

Comment: Looks like you are correct but how do i solve this??